# GetWindowRect reports same dialog window size, but actual size is different between Windows 7 vs Windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I created a dialog window that is displayed properly in Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2013 displayed on a monitor with a resolution of 1920x1080 using DPI 125%. I built the project using the same Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 10 with the same resolution and DPI.

However, the dialog window size is smaller on Windows 10 than on Windows 7. I used `GetWindowRect` to check the width and height between the two operating systems, but both reports the same size of `width = 579` and `height = 408`.

When I did a print screen capture of the dialog box, the actual size is different as shown, causing some display issues:

[image]
[image]

I am trying to properly scale the dialog sizes between both operating systems, but I'm having a difficult time understanding why it reports the same size in code, but different in actual display?

Not sure if this helps but the project settings has `High DPI Aware` for `DPI Awareness`. I've also set `Per Monitor High DPI Aware`, which did not help.

Comment: Are those sizes the size of the window or the client area?  This could be due to the window border being different sizes.

Comment: the actual size of the dialog window including title bar and close button

Comment: Windows 7 and 10 use different sizes for borders and captions. Design your window in terms of the desired client area size, and use `AdjustWindowRect/Ex()` to calculate the needed window size to produce the desired client area size.